# Open Declaration com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.insert() giving error unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage, json-api

I have written java code to upload files to google cloud storage referring `https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert`, it was working earlier but since from 3 days insert.execute is not working by saying

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Please guide me how to get GCS ssl certificate.

also it will be helpful if you give information about how often GCS certificate change

Thanks and Regards,

Ajay K N

Comment: Please include all required information (like you code) in the post. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was our company firewall got regular updates due to some recent update it was blocking the communication, We raised the request to add exception to application hosted machine and exception got resolved.

Thanks and Regards,
Ajay K N